# CSS for cycling through multiple images to decorate unordered list bullets

Tags: html, css

I want to replace a bullet with one from a collection of images

```
<ul>
    <li> List item 1 </li>
    <li> list item 2 </li>
    <li> List item 3 </li>
    <li> List item 4 </li>
</ul>
```

I know it's possible to define an image in css as part of the `list-style-image` css attribute:

```
ul{
list-style-image: url('/images/circle.jpg');
}
```

but this is applies a single image to all bullets. What I'd like to do is provide a sequence of images, and have each bullet display a different image from the list in turn, wrapping as appropriate.

For example, if I provided a sequence of images`['red.jpg','amber.jpg','green.jpg']`, if I applied that to an unordered list of 8 bullets, I'd like it to decorate those list items using the images in the sequence `[red, amber, green, red, amber, green, red, amber]`.

Is there a `<ul>` or `<li>` method of styling this, or should I construct some other markup separately that does the same thing, just not using `<ul>`/`<li>`?

e.g. what's the closest I can get to the below?

```
ul.traffic_lights {
list-style-image: [url('/images/red_circle.jpg', url('/images/amber_circle.jpg', url('/images/green_circle.jpg');
}
```

Comment: Just done a quick search on the same - never heard of `nth-of-type` it before now - but yes! that looks an ideal fit - especially the variant with a formula specification - you put that in an answer, it'd be a strong candidate. I'll try it now on `<ul>` (or perhaps it should apply to `<li>` with a `content` attribute) to see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nth-of-type` should do it.

You can adapat the styling as required but this sets the pattern.

```css
li {
  font-size: 2em;
}

li:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
  color: red;
}

li:nth-of-type(3n+2) {
  color: yellow;
}

li:nth-of-type(3n+3) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
  <li>Item 9</li>
  <li>Item 10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, that works a charm! Though I notice that this method will also flavour both ordered list elements and unordered list elements as well (nothing that can't be fixed with some additional class specification though). I did also try `nth-child` but might need to experiment with that separately. Thankyou very much!

Comment: Differentiating between `ul` and `ol` `li` is just a matter of the parent selector.

Comment: Aha yes, I got it : `ul > li:nth-of-type(5n+1) {  background: red; }` thanks again :)